# How do I forget neighbours' (never-joined) Wi-Fi networks?

Tags: mac, network, wifi, imac, macos

My WiFi can see 12 networks belonging to neighbours, locked and password protected, some with silly names. Network/Wi-Fi/Advanced allows me to remove names from the list, but **only for networks I have joined**. How can I remove the others?

Comment: Network/Wi-Fi/Advanced will not allow you to remove *any* names from the list of *currently available* networks.

Answer (score 1):

Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced allows you to remove *preferred* networks. Preferred means that they are recognized (i.e. previously-connected-to) networks and you can set a priority order should multiple networks be available simultaneously. These networks will still appear in the list of available networks when they are nearby after removal from Preferred.

There is no way to remove network SSIDs from the list of currently-available networks.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot remove someone else's network**, unless you can convince them to turn off their hardware or hide their SSID.

**One option** is to get creative writing an applescript to hide all networks if your preferred network is available.